# ServiceEndpoint and ResourceManagerEndpoint values do not match existing environment. Please use Environment parameter

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, octopus-deploy

I have a PowerShell script running in Octopus Deploy as part of my deployment process. An extract of the script is below:

```
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile "myAzurePublishSetting.PublishSettings"
Select-AzureSubscription 'mySubscription'
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName 'mySubscription' -Environment 'myEnvironment' -CurrentStorageAccountName 'myStorageAccount'
```

I'm now getting the below error from the `Set-AzureSubscription` cmdlet:

```
ServiceEndpoint and ResourceManagerEndpoint values do not match existing environment. Please use Environment parameter.
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.SetAzureSubscriptionCommand.ExecuteCmdlet()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
```

Octopus Deploy is hosted in an Azure virtual machine. This script worked fine until a few days ago so maybe Azure has changed something since nothing else has changed.

It's even more puzzling since I can run this script successfully on the virtual machine in both a PowerShell window and using `Calamari.exe` which is apparently what Octopus uses under the hood to call the script.

Any ideas?

Comment: Environment parameter is used to choose "AzureCloud" or "AzureChinaCloud" and so on. Are you using one of these ?

Comment: @Pradebban Raja yes I'm using the "AzureCloud" value for the `-Environment` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have made changes to Azure subscriptions, for example disabling a subscription. Powershell still has a cache of the previous subscriptions. Use Get-AzureAccount to get the Id of the account and then Remove-AzureAccount. Finally, add the account again using Add-AzureAccount.